# Makefile `echo -n' not working

Tags: bash, makefile, echo

I am trying to have my Makefile echo text without the trailing new line, but am unable to. I am experiencing the behavior on OS X (on Linux everything works as expected).

#### Makefile

```
a:
    @echo -n "hello"

b:
    @echo -n hello

c:
    @/bin/echo -n "hello"
```

Output:

```
$make a
-n hello
$make b
hello$make c
hello$
```

In other words, the `make a` is broken. What exactly is happening? Is make using a built-in echo? Clearly the presence of the double quotes changes the behavior, but why?

#### Update

As discovered by @chepner, using the full path to `/bin/echo` in the makefile understands the -n flag correctly.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Something about the quotes confuses `make`. Your code behaves the same for me, but the following works as expected:

```
help:
        @echo -n Shouldn\'t print a newline
```

Hardcoding the path to the executable also works:

```
help:
        @/bin/echo -n "Shouldn't print a newline"
```

The Mac OS X man page for `echo`, while discussing the existence of shell built-in `echo`s, mentions that the `echo` of `sh(1)` does not support the `-n` option, but that fails to explain (to me, anyway) why my first alternative works.

---

Confirmation that `make` is using `sh` to execute the commands by default. [Make manual 5.3.2 Choosing the Shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Choosing-the-Shell.html) specifies this hehavrior:

> The program used as the shell is taken from the variable SHELL. If
> this variable is not set in your makefile, the program /bin/sh is used
> as the shell. The argument(s) passed to the shell are taken from the
> variable .SHELLFLAGS. The default value of .SHELLFLAGS is -c normally,
> or -ec in POSIX-conforming mode.

In

```
SHELL = bash
help:
        @echo -n "Shouldn't print a newline"
        @echo -n Shouldn\'t print a newline
```

both echo statements behave the same (no newlines printed). So without that variable, we have `bash` pretending to be `sh`, but evaluating the two lines differently. Question 1: why? Question 2: is the second line the native `bash` echo or `/bin/echo`, rather than the emulated `sh` `echo`?

Comment: Actually, I had just realized this and was changing my question to reflect it. But why exactly is `make` confused...and how could I make it explicit to `make` that I want to pass the -n flag to echo (without the explicit path?) Is make using some sort of built in echo?

Comment: The entire recipe is executed using the shell specified by `$SHELL`, or `/bin/sh` if that variable isn't set. So ordinarily, if the shell in question has a built-in, it will use that unless the path is hardcoded. The odd thing here is that despite `$SHELL` being set to '/usr/local/bin/bash' (for me, anyway), the problem line seems to executed using the `sh` built-in, not the `bash` built-in.

Comment: I was having issues with the `-e` flag earlier, so it's all flags that confuses make for some odd reason...

Answer (score 35):

The problem comes from the *unfortunate* interaction of two facts.

First, `make` has two modes of operations depending on the complexity of the recipe to be run:

- If the command is *easy*, `make` will directly run the recipe with its builtin commands. This is what happens in your `b` case.
- If the command is *complex*, `make` will spawn a shell to interpret and run the recipe. This is what happens in your `a` case.

Second, `make` uses `/bin/sh` as a shell but the functionality of `/bin/sh` is implemented differently on Mac OS X and Linux:

- On Mac OS X, the functionality of `/bin/sh` is implemented by `bash`. Also on Mac OS X, `bash` is compiled with `--enable-strict-posix-default`. One consequence of this flag is that the `echo` command does not understand the `-n` flag.
- On Linux, the functionality of `/bin/sh` is implemented by `dash` which is less strict with respect to POSIX specification. Therefore the flag `-n` is implemented in the `echo` command.

BTW, the Makefile buitlin `echo` command understands the `-n` flag which explains why the `b` case always works.

The clean and portable way of fixing your problem is to replace your `@echo -n` recipes with `@printf` recipes.

Comment: Somewhat related: on Mac Lion 10.7 at least, root's default shell is /bin/sh not /bin/bash.  Best to use 'chsh' command to change this to /bin/bash (no arguments necessary) so that 'echo -n' works in .bashrc etc.

Answer (score 3):

echo is a bash shell builtin, but when you run it from makefile, it is the program version

Comment: `-n` is supported by both the built-in and the standalone program.

Comment: The program version (/bin/echo) actually supports -n, so if the Makefile was using /bin/echo, it would work correct.