# configure: make: echo: Command not found

Tags: ruby, linux, gcc, gnu-make

When I try to install Ruby from source, no matter what the version is, I am getting the following error.

```
$ ./configure



....
....
checking whether gcc needs -traditional... no
checking for ld... ld
checking whether the linker is GNU ld... yes
checking whether gcc -E accepts -o... yes
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for ar... ar
checking for as... as
checking for objdump... objdump
checking for objcopy... objcopy
checking for nm... nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... no
....
....
....
checking if make is GNU make... make: echo: Command not found
make: *** [all] Error 127
no
checking for safe null command for make... :
checking for nroff... /usr/bin/nroff`
```

I tried to fix the error by installing `gcc` and `g++` but that doesn't help.

The full detailed log available here: https://gist.github.com/satnami/8ac0688c287a8d5c859c5ba064d9bfca

#### Extra details

**Linux version**:

`Linux version 4.4.0-104-generic(buildd@lgw01-amd64-030 (gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) )`

**gcc version**:

`gcc version 4.8.5 (Ubuntu 4.8.5-2ubuntu1~14.04.1)`

**OpenssL version**:

`OpenSSL 1.0.2g-fips  1 Mar 2016`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was because of missing file which is

> /bin/echo

related to 
[Makefile `echo -n' not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11675070/makefile-echo-n-not-working)

Answer (score 1):

It's better to include at least the relevant info here, such as what operating system and OS release you're using.  From the gist output it seems you're using some version of GNU/Linux.  If we knew which distribution (for example, Ubuntu) we could be more helpful.

Maybe you don't have `echo` available... what is your `PATH` set to?  On many systems, `echo` lives in `/bin/echo` so make sure you have `/bin` on your `PATH`.

Note that running `echo foo` in your shell is *not* good enough, because your shell is likely bash which has a built-in echo.  However, make will run `/bin/sh` not bash, and `/bin/sh` may be something like dash which doesn't have a built-in echo (depending on which Linux distribution you're using).

Comment: thanks, I just updated the question, /bin is included and echo is running well in /bin/sh

Comment: This seems to be more a request for clarification (and so should be a comment) rather than an answer.  At least, this answer now appears in the LQP review queue so I'm probably not the only person to think that.